# Why does IntelliJ IDEA create a /out/production/src file structure when running a project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've imported a small example Java program to mess around with, and when I run it using IntelliJ IDEA it creates a clone of the `/src/` folder in `/out/production/src/`

What is the reasoning behind this? Have I imported my source code incorrectly or am I using an incorrect Project Structure?

The application runs exactly how I expect it to, but the file structure for `/out/production/` is **all-in-red** in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Sometimes it happens but the color is red, not white.

Comment: In my case it is red, as though it's got errors. The code runs, I'm more interested in why does IntelliJ IDEA add this whole new cloned file structure? It seems pointless.

Comment: Could you upload a picture with the project structure?

Comment: OK! I'm pretty silly, it's the compiled .class files - I don't come from a Java background, so I guess I didn't expect them to be dumped in the middle of  the project structure (and messing up my file versioning too...). I think these are completely harmless.

Comment: If you add them to the vcs they should be **all-in-green**, but these files are not a source code and should be excluded from vcs.

Answer (score 1):

It's the compiled .class files.

I obviously don't use Java or IntelliJ IDEA often enough.

Comment: Kind of ridiculous that these still end up within the project in 2019, as if version control systems don't exist